# Populate a second DataGrid once I double click on a row WPF

Tags: wpf, events, datagrid, wpfdatagrid, delegatecommand

I am still a little new to wpf and MVVM.  I am trying to code a solution without breaking that pattern.  I have two (well three, but for the scope of this question just two) `DataGrid`s.  I want to double click on the row of one, and from that load data Into the second `DataGrid` (ideally I would spin up a second thread that would load the data).  So far I can get a window to pop up when I double click on a row.  I throw the code for the event into the code behind for the xaml.  To me that seems very windows formish.  Somehow or the other I feel like that breaks the pattern a great deal.

```
private void DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    if (popDataGrid.SelectedItem == null) {
        return;
    }
    var selectedPopulation = popDataGrid.SelectedItem as PopulationModel;
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("The Population you double clicked on has this ID - {0}, Name - {1}, and Description {2}", selectedPopulation.populationID, selectedPopulation.PopName, selectedPopulation.description));
}
```

That is the code for the event in the code behind and here is the grids definition in the xaml:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PopulationCollection}" Name="popDataGrid"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
          CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="296,120,0,587" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="503" Grid.Column="1" 
          MouseDoubleClick="DataGrid_MouseDoubleClick">
</DataGrid>
```

I am thinking this code should go in the MainWindowViewModel.  So I am attempting to create a command:

```
public ICommand DoubleClickPopRow { get { return new DelegateCommand(OnDoubleClickPopRow); }}
```

and the same event handler:

```
private void OnDoubleClickPopRow(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
}
```

But the `ICommand` is throwing an exception when it returns the `DelegateCommand(OnDoubleClickPopRow)`.

Well, one can plainly see that the number of arguments doesn't match.  I know I am doing something wrong, but I am not quite sure what it is.  I will continue to research this but any help you guys can give would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PopulationCollection}" Name="popDataGrid"
AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected"
CanUserAddRows="False" Margin="296,120,0,587" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="503"  Grid.Column="1" SelectedItem="{Binding ItemInViewModel}"></DataGrid>
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Save_Bid}" />
</i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

You can add this to your `DataGrid` and add your code in your viewmodel.
Now that we have a selected item bound to an item in our view model we can use that item to know when we can fire the even we want as well as what item to use when the event is fired When the event can be fired

```
bool Can_Fire_Event()
{
if(ItemInViewModel != null)
{ return true; } else { return false; }
}
private RelayCommand _saveBid;
public ICommand SaveBid
{
get
{
if (_saveBid == null)
{
_saveBid = new RelayCommand(param => Save_Bid(), param => Can_Fire_Event());
}
return _saveBid;
}
}

public void Save_Bid()
{
//Open your new Window here, using your "ItemInViewModel" because this event couldn't be fired from your datagrid unless the "ItemInViewModel" had a value assigned to it

}
```

Comment: Where would I add this code?  I tried adding it to my before My DataGridTextColumns rows.  What about that names space?  I am getting an exception telling me it can't find it?  Is there a dll I need to download?

Comment: I am still confused on how to implement this.  Could you suggest some reading?

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75e13d71-7c53-4382-9592-6c07c6a00207&displaylang=en Download the SDK which is free

Comment: I was loading the wrong dll... But I still don't understand per-se  how to capture the event and lets say display a window with a message and all the items from the row of that data element?

Comment: So your command that your firing would go to a relay command in your view model. From your view model you would also have a selected item bound to your grid. So when double click happens, in your view model you would know what item has been double clicked and you could open a new window from there as well as set the data context for that new window.

Comment: Could you give me an example and update your code?  For instance, obviously in my view model I have the collection and the instance that I just clicked on, but how would I refer to it?  Using a code behind I just used the DataContext and from there I got the specific row that I clicked on...

Comment: Ah, Selected Item is kind of what I am looking for...  I will study your code and see what I come up with.  So far so good.  What is Can_Fire_Event  ... Did you mean MouseDoubleClick?

Comment: Can fire event will return false if there is no selected item. If it is false then the event can't fire. If you attach a relay command to a button like this it will auto disable the button for you.